# MVC 4 WebApi Formatter Messing Up My Entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, model-binding, azure-table-storage

I am using MVC 4 WebApi to post several entities to Azure Table Storage. I believe that it's using formatting and not model binding because these are complex types (classes I've written) and they're being sent to the API in the body, not the URI.

This is working well for all of the entities except for one (a class called Comment), which points to the other entities (it has properties of the other entities). The JSON that I pass into the API in the body has 2  properties that contain other entities.

For Azure Table Storage, each entity has a RowKey attribute. I've noticed that once my controller builds the entity from the JSON in the request body (using the MVC4 formatting), it has the wrong value for the RowKey - it actually has the value for one of the entities referenced in the 2 properties that I mentioned. This other entity's RowKey attribute is also included in the JSON - so the JSON has 3 RowKeys, but they're all properly located in the JSON to be part of the correct entity. The Formatter just seems to be reading it wrong.

I can't save this Comment. I don't think the key problem is the reason, because the Table Storage service shouldn't care (there's no validation), but I believe that this is just part of a problem that makes the entity unsaveable by the Azure Table Storage service. Has anyone had similar problems with MVC formatting like this?

Thanks!

**Edit**
I forgot to mention - for testing, if I instantiate a new Comment entity inside the same controller method where the formatter is breaking, it saves just fine. So I'm fairly certain that the problem is occurring in the WebApi's parsing of the entity being passed to the controller's Post method.

Adding JSON and Model:

```
{
  "PartitionKey": "US",
  "RowKey": "com-dd1920ed-2e87-4f51-a6d1-32fa692aadae",
  "AboutKey": "US|per-fb1de571-7142-47c8-bdb3-0eddd59f6ccd",
  "FromPersonKey": "US|per-4c3261d8-3b1a-4bd4-8850-4d769cfbd7ef",
  "CommentText": "Testing Create.",
  "FromPerson": {
    "PartitionKey": "US",
    "RowKey": "per-4c3261d8-3b1a-4bd4-8850-4d769cfbd7ef",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Smith",
    "NickName": null,
    "FullName": "John Smith",
    "Description": null,
    "ImageLocation": null,
    "Region": "US"
  },
  "About": {
    "PartitionKey": "US",
    "RowKey": "per-fb1de571-7142-47c8-bdb3-0eddd59f6ccd",
    "FirstName": "George",
    "LastName": "Martin",
    "NickName": "Cowboy Hat",
    "FullName": "George Martin",
    "Description": "Ten gallons big.",
    "ImageLocation": null,
    "Region": "US"
  },
  "CommentDateTime": "2012-08-25T13:41:09.8899185Z"
}
```

Model (bound wrong from JSON, posted from debugging locals window). Another problem you'll notice here is that the "About" property is null. This should be a Person object, but Json.Net doesn't seem to be parsing this property, presumably because it's a type of interface rather than a class. Obviously here, it's a person that's being passed in that property in the JSON, but it could be something else, hence the use of an interface there:

```
comment         {Classes.Comment}                           Classes.Comment  
About           null                                        Classes.ICommentable  
AboutKey        US|per-fb1de571-7142-47c8-bdb3-0eddd59f6ccd string  
CommentDateTime {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}                      System.DateTime  
CommentText     Testing Create.                             string  
FromPerson      {Classes.Person}                            Classes.Person  
FromPersonKey   US|per-4c3261d8-3b1a-4bd4-8850-4d769cfbd7ef string  
PartitionKey    US                                          string  
RowKey          per-fb1de571-7142-47c8-bdb3-0eddd59f6ccd    string
```

Comment: could you post the actual sample JSONs and the model after it's been wrongly binded?

Comment: Sure - just posted the JSON, model is coming ...

Comment: Anybody?? I'm not familiar enough with MVC formatting to understand why this JSON isn't being read properly.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm using EF with DB first, receiving synced data from the DB in an Android phone formatting directly from the cursor, so didn't notice that I apparently couldn't decide whether the timestamp should be named "create_ts" or "created_ts".  Once I decided, the world was once again bright, shiny and new.  I exist to serve, if only as a lesson to others...